# Mongodb cursor.toArray() has become the bottle neck

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb

Mongodb cursor.toArray() has become the bottle neck. I need to process 2 million documents and output to a file. I am processing 10,000 at a time using skip and limit options but it didn’t quite work. so I was looking for a driver that is more memory efficient. I have also tried to process 10 documents at a time and it takes forever so I am not sure if .each() can solve the problem? Also does .nextObject makes a network call every time we retrieve a single document?

Node.js also has an internal limit of 1.5GB on memory so I am not sure how I can process these documents. I do believe that this problem can be solved just by using the mongo cursor in the right way at the application level and not doing any database level aggregations.

Comment: Streaming the query results is typically the way to go for a use case like this; have you tried that?  Look at [`cursor.stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream).

Comment: Not yet. I can try that within a few mins but do you have any idea how that can be memory efficient or how it is different from cursor.toArray() or cursor.each()? other words any idea on how it works internally?

Comment: `.nextObject()` does make a network call, but a very lightweight one that is meant to be very fast. `.each()` is the way to go. File I/O will definitely become your bottleneck (under normal conditions).

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need to hold all the documents since you can write each document to the file as it is received from the server. If you use a cursor with `.each` and a `batchSize`, you can write each document to the file, holding no more than `batchSize` documents on the client side:

```
db.collection.find(query, { "batchSize" : 100 }).each(writeToFile)
```

From the [Node.js driver API docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each)

> the cursor will only hold a maximum of batch size elements at any given time if batch size is specified

Using skip and limit to break up results is a bad idea. A query with a skip of `n` and a limit of `m` generally has to scan at least `n + m` documents or index entries. If you paginate with skip and limit, you end up making the amount of work the query has to do quadratic in the size of (total number of results / limit), e.g. for 1000 docs and a limit of 100, the total docs scanned would be on the order of

```
100 + 200 + 300 + 400 + ... + 1000 = 100 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + 10)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response and I understand that I am giving a quadratic amount of work to the database server however I thought I am holding no more than the documents specified in the limit using the skip and limit options in memory at a time. Am I not? The issue here is a memory bottle neck so when you say "scan" does that happen on the client side or on the server side of the DB? other words how does skip and limit work on the client side (does it bring in all the documents and then skips x amount of documents and limits to whatever the number specified by the client?)

Comment: your intuition is correct. `skip` and `limit` relieve stress on the client-side (where your problem is), but are not particularly efficient on the server side when sorting on un-indexed fields

Comment: Are you sure you mean "relieve stress"? I thought it would actually cause more stress on the client side. The main issue here is the memory bottleneck and I can see when I run my process and monitor using top command. I clearly understand that skip and limit causes more over work as beautifully put by @wdberkeley (but I am still not sure if it is on the server side or the client side). According to you you say it is on the server side however I don't see how that can be a memory bottleneck. I could see that it can be a network bottleneck but not memory.